# dotnet hotchocolate azure function isolated (how to access conString and jwt options from host.json)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, hotchocolate

[image]

How do I access connectionString and jwtSwitting in 'host.settings.json'?

like this (it's not hotchocolate project, it's normal dotnet api):
appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost; User=root; Database=FINDUS; Password=xxxxxx"
  },
  "JwtSettings": {
    "SigningKey": "23kfioejrkdjfkelrkdoemvasde31sxnmd",
    "Issuer":"CwkSocial",
    "Audiences":["SwaggerUI"]
  }
}
```

Program.cs(access jwtSettings):

```
 var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
            builder.Configuration.Bind(nameof(JwtSettings), jwtSettings);
            var jwtSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtSettings));

            builder.Services.Configure<JwtSettings>(jwtSection);
```

the example is not hotchocolate project.

Comment: Please don't post sensitive information. I edit the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing variables in isolated `local.settings.json` you could try this:
`JwtSettings.cs`

```
    public class JwtSettings
    {
        public string? SigningKey { get; set; }
        public string? Issuer { get;set; }
        public List<string>? Audiences { get; set; }
    }
```

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

JwtSettings jwtSettings = config.GetSection("JwtSettings").Get<JwtSettings>();
```

Test
[image]